# AWS Amplify custom CDK Lambda deployment

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy a custom Lambda resource on AWS Amplify, but I get an error saying that the S3 bucket doesn't exist. I assume that it's because I use `lambda.Code.fromAsset(...)`, but the CDK documentation doesn't mention anything that I need to add some S3 bucket. It's a fresh Amplify app, so I couldn't mess up anything with configuration before.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchBucket. S3 Error Message: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400
```

Repro steps:

1. Create Amplify app
2. Type `amplify add custom` to add custom resource and select CDK
3. Add stack definition in generated cd-stack.ts
4. `amplify push`

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as AmplifyHelpers from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import path from "path"

export class cdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps, amplifyResourceProps?: AmplifyHelpers.AmplifyResourceProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    /* Do not remove - Amplify CLI automatically injects the current deployment environment in this input parameter */
    new cdk.CfnParameter(this, 'env', {
      type: 'String',
      description: 'Current Amplify CLI env name',
    });    
  
    const amplifyProjectInfo = AmplifyHelpers.getProjectInfo();

    const funcResourceNamePrefix = `func-${amplifyProjectInfo.projectName}`;
    const func = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      handler: 'index.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../myfunction/')),
      functionName: `${funcResourceNamePrefix}-${cdk.Fn.ref('env')}`,
    });
  }
}
```

I already tried to deploy additional S3 but it doesn't help. I see in generated cloudformation that this lambda points to some bucket, but it doesn't exist. Is it somehow autogenerated? How can I recreate and use this bucket?

```json
    "MyFunction3BAA72D1": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Fn::Sub": "cdk-hnb659fds-assets-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}"
          },
          "S3Key": "c4b0207499ed4bf5fa0062eeeab46178e1968835fa4a82c11da08a81bdcad438.zip"
        },
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "MyFunctionServiceRole3C357FF2",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "FunctionName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "func-testapp-",
              {
                "Ref": "env"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "Handler": "index.handler",
        "Runtime": "nodejs16.x"
      }
    }
```

Comment: I asked technical support once how I can build Lambda with the CDK using `amplify add custom`, and at the time of writing, they said the only way to do it was with `amplify add function` in the `CLI`. Does your Lambda build?

Comment: @Luke No, it doesn't. Did they say why only `amplify add function` is supposed to work?
As I undestand, we should be able to use CDK to deploy anything we want.

Comment: I don't quite understand why `amplify add custom` for lambda does not build them. You are right, we can build with the CDK with Lambda, however, I think you'll need a separate CDK deployment that is not a part of your AWS Amplify project.